# Spark RDD transformations exception when accessing MapPartitionsRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to extract predictions from a MatrixFactorizationModel by mapping an RDD of users to the recommendProducts method of the model. This gives me a MapPartitionsRDD. Trying to then reduce or otherwise access this RDD gives me a Spark Exception.

Here is the simplified code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{ALS, Rating, MatrixFactorizationModel}

val users = sc.parallelize(List(1,2))
val trainingData = sc.parallelize(List(Rating(1,1,0.5),Rating(1,2,0.5),Rating(2,1,1),Rating(2,3,1))).cache()

val model = ALS.trainImplicit(trainingData, 6, 20, 0.1, 2)

val recommendations = users.map(model.recommendProducts(_,2))

recommendations.first
```

The error occurs on the last line:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 11500.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 11500.0 (TID 6401, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$sc(RDD.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.lookup(PairRDDFunctions.scala:928)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.recommendProducts(MatrixFactorizationModel.scala:168)
```

My only theory is that thatMapPartitionRDDs have not actually applied the function when created, and so if the recommendProducts method of the model performs some kind of implicit RDD function, perhaps it only calls this method when the data is accessed and so we get an attempted nested RDD call. In which case, would that mean that it is not possible to perform any operations on MatrixFactorizationModels in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, looking at the source of the MatrixFactorizationModel, I can see that it internally stores user and product features as RDDs. Thus, any calls to this model must be done from the master. To run my code, I had to flatten my users in order to use the iterative non-RDD version of map:

```
val recommendations = users.collect.toList.map(model.recommendProducts(_,2))

recommendations.head
```